# Ошибка формата даты и времени (но формат корректный)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Всем привет.
Имеется проект на ASP.NET MVC

В нем есть форма создания обьекта.

У обьекта есть селект выбора типа объекта.

У объекта первого типа есть 2 поля для вводы даты (дата начала и конца)

У объекта второго типа 1 поле ввода (дата начала)

```
        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
        <label>Тип</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Repeatable, new List<SelectListItem>() { new SelectListItem() { Value = false.ToString(), Text = "Однократное" }, new SelectListItem() { Value = true.ToString(), Text = "Регулярное" } }, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartDate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm}", new { @class = "form-control", @type="hidden" })
        <input id="StartDateLocal" class="form-control" placeholder="С момента создания" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EndDate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm}", new { @class = "form-control", @type="hidden" })
        <input id="EndDateLocal" class="form-control" placeholder="Неограниченно" />
    </div>

   $("#StartDateLocal")
   .datetimepicker($.extend({}, DEFAULT_DATEPICKER_PARAMS, {
       format: "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm"
   }))
   .on("dp.change", function () {
       $("#StartDate").val(new moment($(this).val(), "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm").utc().format("DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm"));
   })
   .val($("#StartDate").val() ? new moment.utc($("#StartDate").val(), "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm").local().format("DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm") : "")



$("#EndDateLocal")
       .datetimepicker($.extend({}, DEFAULT_DATEPICKER_PARAMS, {
           format: "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm"
       }))
       .on("dp.change", function () {
           $("#EndDate").val(new moment($(this).val(), "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm").utc().format("DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm"));
       })
       .val($("#EndDate").val() ? new moment.utc($("#EndDate").val(), "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm").local().format("DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm") : "")
```

Столкнулся с проблемой.

Обьекты 1 типа создаются прекрасно.

Объекты 2 типа не создаются

Возникает ошибка

"DateTime should be in format 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss'"

Если схитрить. И выбрать обьект 1 типа, указать обе даты и потом в выпадающем списке выбратб объект 2 типа, то тогда создается обьект второго типа (с 2 датами в базе, конечно же)

Я пробовал подставлять значение для конечной даты в коде, так как если даты окончания нет, то приходит null.
Но даже с подставленным в коде значением возникает та же ошибка. Хотя формат даты, полученной в коде соответствует шаблону.

Как это можно побороть, подскажите, пожалуйста.